# determining percentages with php

Tags: php, mysql, percentage

I am trying to determine the percentage of number of student passing a test either on 1st attempt or 2nd attempt. I believe I have the code correct but when I echo the results I get no output.

```
<?php
$NREMT1 = "SELECT nremtcognitive FROM course_students WHERE nremtcognitive = '1' ";
$NREMT2 = "SELECT nremtcognitive FROM course_students WHERE nremtcognitive >= '2' ";
$completed = "SELECT studentstatus FROM course_students WHERE studentstatus >='4'";

$getNREMT1 = mysql_query($NREMT1);
$fetchNREMT1= mysql_num_rows($getNREMT1);
$getNREMT2 = mysql_query($NREMT2);
$fetchNREMT2= mysql_num_rows($getNREMT2);
$getcompleted = mysql_query($completed);
$fetchcompleted= mysql_num_rows($getcompleted);

function percent($fetchNREMT1, $fetchNREMT2, $fetchcompleted) {
    $NREMT1count= $fetchNREMT1/$fetchcompleted;
    $NREMT1percent= $NREMT1count * 100;
    $NREMT1result = number_format($NREMT1percent,0);

    $NREMT2count= $fetchNREMT2/$fetchcompleted;
    $NREMT2percent= $NREMT2count * 100;
    $NREMT2result = number_format($NREMT2percent,0);
}
echo $NREMT1result;
echo $NREMT2result;

?>
```

Comment: So.. what is the function for ? It never gets called...

Comment: Where are you calling the `percent()` function?

Comment: I am guessing you can do this with one single SQL query, but it would be useful to understand more about your table and its data to help formulate that query.

Comment: The function is also missing a return statement...

Answer (score 0):

You are not calling your function `percent` anywhere.

You should call it **and make it return something** or otherwise, just can avoid creating it and put the same code in the same place:

```
 $NREMT1count= $fetchNREMT1/$fetchcompleted;
 $NREMT1percent= $NREMT1count * 100;
 $NREMT1result = number_format($NREMT1percent,0);

 $NREMT2count= $fetchNREMT2/$fetchcompleted;
 $NREMT2percent= $NREMT2count * 100;
 $NREMT2result = number_format($NREMT2percent,0);

 echo $NREMT1result;
 echo $NREMT2result;
```

It seems you don't have it very clear the concept of **function**. You can take a look at [the documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/language.functions.php).

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the variables declared inside `percent()` are never initialized because the function is never called. Try this:

```
<?php
$NREMT1 = "SELECT nremtcognitive FROM course_students WHERE nremtcognitive = '1' ";
$NREMT2 = "SELECT nremtcognitive FROM course_students WHERE nremtcognitive >= '2' ";
$completed = "SELECT studentstatus FROM course_students WHERE studentstatus >='4'";

$getNREMT1 = mysql_query($NREMT1);
$fetchNREMT1= mysql_num_rows($getNREMT1);
$getNREMT2 = mysql_query($NREMT2);
$fetchNREMT2= mysql_num_rows($getNREMT2);
$getcompleted = mysql_query($completed);
$fetchcompleted= mysql_num_rows($getcompleted);

percent($fetchNREMT1, $fetchNREMT2, $fetchcompleted);

function percent($fetchNREMT1, $fetchNREMT2, $fetchcompleted) {
    $NREMT1count= $fetchNREMT1/$fetchcompleted;
    $NREMT1percent= $NREMT1count * 100;
    $NREMT1result = number_format($NREMT1percent,0);

    $NREMT2count= $fetchNREMT2/$fetchcompleted;
    $NREMT2percent= $NREMT2count * 100;
    $NREMT2result = number_format($NREMT2percent,0);

    echo $NREMT1result;
    echo $NREMT2result;
}
?>
```

It is also worth noting that the `mysql_*` family of functions are now deprecated, and you should really consider using MySQLi or PDO.

Answer (score 0):

Just change your query.  Untested, but this should get you started:

```
SELECT 
    SUM(IF(CONVERT(nremtcognitive, UNSIGNED INTEGER) >= 2)) / COUNT(*) 
FROM course_students;
```

Comment: Just curious, I've never indented queries like you've done in this one. Is this a good practice?

Comment: @Sann, Probably not the way I do it.  I don't need SQL queries regularly, and never really pick a format for indenting.  I'm sure there are standards for indentation.  Some indentation is helpful for sure.